# Why does the time taken for AJAX request jump from 2ms to 50ms and higher?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wrote a small script (with jQuery for AJAX) to "ping" the server and output how long it takes for my AJAX requests to occur.

```
var start = Date.now(), end = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax('', {
        complete: function() {
            end = Date.now();

            console.log(end - start);
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

This is the kind of pattern I'm getting:

```
39
2
4
2
3
40
3
2
3
4
2
61
9
4
3
2
2
4
34
```

etc.

Why does the "ping" jump from a low number (2, 3, 4, etc.) to a higher one (40, 50, 60) in such a pattern? Is there an obvious reason or should I just blame it on HTTP/AJAX technology?

Comment: There could be any number of things - a process on your computer using up bandwidth, for example - but depending on the URL that you are loading the first and longer requests could be going to the server while the shorter ones are being returned from the browsers local cache and therefor are faster. It all depends on what you are doing. Also the code, as provided, would only ever increase the output time since you are not reseting `start` value.

Comment: I wonder what AJAX request completes in 2 ms. Are you logging some other variables somewhere else? And the more appropriate way would be to check the request and response time in developer console where more accurate timer is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those requests with about 40ms in your example are real requests. Others are cached results by browser.

Comment: That makes pretty good sense. I'll try appending a query to the request to force a non-cached response.

Comment: It works. Now my results are more realistic (40, 50, 100, 50, constantly).