# IBM Worklight: Get page loading time

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

Suppose I'm loading an external webpage:

```
<mainFile>http://stackoverflow.com</mainFile>
```

How can I calculate how long Worklight takes to load the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do a "ping" in `wlCommonInit()` to see how long it took.

The reason is that `wlCommonInit()` is being called only once the Worklight JS framework has finished loading, so we can assume that once called, the app is loaded. It will be an estimation, but a close enough estimation IMO.

There are all sorts of ways to "ping". Here's one: [Why does the time taken for AJAX request jump from 2ms to 50ms and higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623225/why-does-the-time-taken-for-ajax-request-jump-from-2ms-to-50ms-and-higher)

You'll probably want to optimize the calculation to get as close as real result as you can.